# Using GSuite or Github to Manage who can log into Linux or Windows VMs on Azure

Tags: authentication

I want to manage the members of our team who are able to log into our cloud-hosted VMs, both Linux and Windows.  We currently use [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com) and [GitHub](https://github.com/), to manage access to our code and documentation etc. I would really prefer to not have to also manage a separate Active Directory Domain within our VNets or deal with revoking ssh keys or updating multiple usernames/passwords on every single VM we deploy.

Are there ways to use either GSuite or Github to control login access to our VMs?

If there isn't, what are the best practices to deal with 20+ developers who are all empowered with DevOps responsibilities?

Answer (score 3):

> I would really prefer to not have to also manage a separate Active Directory Domain within our VNets

You've already found the answer: centralized authentication.

If you use a tool like [Okta](https://www.okta.com/partners/gsuite/), you can [indirectly tie GSuite to AD](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en) (or an LDAP server).  And then of course you can [tie OpenSSH there](https://serverfault.com/q/23632/12214) as well.

> or deal with revoking ssh keys

Centralized authentication solves this.

> or updating multiple usernames/passwords on every single VM we deploy.

And this as well.

You've already got the answer, even if you don't like it.

Comment: None of your links and nothing in your answer actually shows how its possible to use Okta to log into a windows or linux machine. It looks like Okta just syncs with Active Directory to let you log into apps.

Comment: @avi and then it's the usual matter of login with an ad account which is the replica of a g-suite account, pbis-open does this for linux, windows does allow login toward a windows Active Directory obviously...

Comment: @avi I added a link to https://serverfault.com/q/23632/12214 which talks about that.

Comment: I'm still not understanding the answer. Will I need to maintain a list of Active Directory users, and give them individual permissions and logins, or will it just use the Gsuite credentials directly?

Comment: @avi You'd manage users in AD, and then Gsuite users get created automatically from there.